weird problem with php DOMElement->replaceWith()
I am seeing some weird behavior that I have not been able to debug. This code is from a simple implementation of a variation on wordpress shortcodes.
The code loops through a DOMNodeList (of custom html tags) and calls another function to process each DOMElement in turn. That function replaces the DOMElement with another DOMElement, and returns the resulting text.
The first time through that loop and function call, everything works exactly as expected. However, the second time through, the call to DOMElement->replaceWith() fails without any exception being thrown. I have checked that each loop and call is working on a distinct DOMElement (tag). I am really stumped.
Any ideas greatly appreciated. Simplified code segments below:
EDIT: here is a more complete code example, trying to avoid pasting too much of my spaghetti here. ;-)
EDIT: added one more bit to make reproducing easier



// for demonstration: this comes from the database
$content = '
<div>
  <p>This is a test ...</p>
  &lt;sc-snippet id="Test Snippet 1"/&gt;
  &lt;sc-snippet id="test-snippet-2"/&gt;
</div>
';

function processContent($content)
{
  $scodes = loadScodes();
  $snames = array_keys($scodes);  
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
  $dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode($content)); // decode the entities in custom tags
  foreach($snames as $sname)
  {
    $scTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName($sname);
    foreach($scTags as $tag)
    {
      $parsed = parseScodeTag($tag, $scodes[$sname]);
      $scode = $parsed['scode'];
      $handler = $scodes[$scode]['handler'];
      $content = $handler($parsed['attrs'], $dom, $tag);
    } // end foreach found tag
  } // end foreach known scode
  return(html_entity_decode($content));  // this should be the HTML segment with tags replaced by snippets

} // end processContent()

function loadScodes()
{
  //$config = config(SCODE_CONFIG);
  //$scodes = $config->get(SCODE_SCODES);
  // for demonstration:
  $scodes = array(
    'sc-snippet' => array(
      'handler' => 'handleSnippet',
      'attrs' => array('id'),
    ),
  );
  return($scodes);
}

// for demonstration, snippets are stored in the database and handled in a different module
function loadSnippet($id)
{
  $snippets = array(
    'Test Snippet 1' => '<p>This is a test snippet 1</p>',
    'test-snippet-2' => '<p>This is a test snippet 2</p>',
  );
  return($snippets[$id]);
}


function parseScodeTag($tag, $scode)
{ 
  $parsed = array();
  $parsed['scode'] = $tag->nodeName;
  $parsed['handler'] = $scode['handler'];
  $scodeAttrs = array();
  if ( isset($scode['attrs']) && count($scode['attrs']) > 0 )
  {
    foreach ($scode['attrs'] as $attr)
    {
      $attrVal = $tag->getAttribute($attr);
      $scodeAttrs[$attr] = $attrVal;
    } 
  }
  $parsed['attrs'] = $scodeAttrs;
  return($parsed);
}

function handleSnippet($attrs, $dom, $tag)
{ // return a block of html
  // check for attributes
  if (!isset($attrs['id']))
  {
    return($dom->saveHTML());
  }
  $snip = loadSnippet($attrs['id']);

  $e = $dom->createElement('div', $snip);
  try {
    $tag->replaceWith($e);
  } catch(Exception $e) { // never get here
    _dd('CAUGHT', false);
  } finally { // correction, do not get here on the second time through
    _dd('FINALLY', false);
  }
  return($dom->saveHTML());
}



getElementsByTagName is "live", it always reflects the current state of the DOM. So if you remove/replace some of the elements you are actually iterating over, this can easily lead to problems of this sort, because elements following the removed/replaced one, "move up" in the list. Can't tell for sure if that is actually what's going on here, due to your incomplete example (proper [mre], please, when you ask here, not just snippets that lack context), but iterating over the nodes in reverse order usually helps to avoid such problems.

thanks for the response. i apologize for not being more complete in my code example, i will try to provide a more complete example. i did not know that about getElementsByTagName, i will try to determine of that is the issue.

If that's the problem, simply convert the NodeList to an array and use that.

it looks like that was indeed the problem, thanks for the input. i simply reversed the loop order by using a for() instead of foreach().

C3roe put me on the right track, the problem was the fact that getElementsByTagName() is "live". i used their suggestion to go through the elements in reverse order, and that seems to have done the trick.
thank you C3roe!!!
  foreach($snames as $sname)
  {
    $scTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName($sname);
    $nTags = $scTags->length;
    for($i = $nTags; $i > 0 ; $i--)
    {
      $tag = $scTags[$i - 1];
      $parsed = parseScodeTag($tag, $scodes[$sname]);
      $scode = $parsed['scode'];
      $handler = $scodes[$scode]['handler'];
      $content = $handler($parsed['attrs'], $dom, $tag);
    } // end for each tag, in reverse order
  } // end foreach known scode

